# Fake Webcam / Webcam Emulator Mac Os 10.7.4 64Bit running as a Virtual Machine.

Tags: macos, virtualization, adobe-flash, webcam, 64-bit

I am looking for fake webcam solution for Mac OS 10.7.4 64bit running as a Virtual Machine.

What I tried:
ManyCam - only works with 32bit Browser and then not with all flash applications
CamCamX - crashes on startup
CamTwist - Crash

Is there any other solution out there?

Comment: I've never had a problem with CamTwist since Leopard all the way through now (10.8.1). I would suggest trying to contact the developer. Commented and not answered since you exclude it in your Question.

Comment: the problem occurs because , quartz extreme isn't available in MacOS Vms. I have a MacOS Server , starting several VMs for testing reasons.

Answer (score 1):

OS X's Quartz Extreme video processing framework and services are not available under OS X 10.7.4 when running inside any kind of Virtual Machine.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [iGlasses](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/)? It's not free but I think there is a demo.